# Why do I get this warning from ag-grid, agMultiColumnFilter component was not found?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to add ag multi column filter, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-multi/

But getting the following warning ag-Grid:

> Looking for component [agMultiColumnFilter] but it wasn't found.

Comment: Did you check your version vs multiColumn's release version ?

Comment: You are right, needed to upgrade versions

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your license key added properly.

Multicolumn filter supports with AG Grid Enterprise version not with Community.

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/licensing/

```
import {LicenseManager} from "ag-grid-enterprise";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("license-key");
```